# Make this the only selectable layer keyboard shortcut not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, select, shortcuts

I've build in a shortcut for the "make this the only selectable layer" command (Ctrl+Alt+Z) on ArcMap, but when I try to use it, I can't seem to get it to work. I have my layer highlighted in the TOC but the command doesn't work, I even try to right click it but it doesn't work either.

This seems like a rather simplistic problem but I just don´t understand how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to replicate the same issue in ArcMap 10.7.  I too could not assign a shortcut to the *Make This the Only Selectable Layer* command.  Initially I thought this is one of those subversive changes ESRI have introduced in their attempt to phase out ArcMap.  But I was able to create a CRTL+K for the Measure tool or even the Add Data button.

This made me think that there may be a set of commands that shortcuts simply don't work with. Think of this scenario you had successfully created a short cut to *Make This the Only Selectable Layer* but you have no layer selected in the TOC or you have multiple layers selected or even no layers in the TOC and then you go press the shortcut, what should happen? ArcMap blow up, fail gracefully or send an angry warning message?  None of those happen when you use the tool as to use it you *have* to click on a layer.

Comment: Perfect, I guess the shortcut was too weird for it to be acceptable, I changed it and was able to make it work properly with Ctrl+K. On a sidenote, I was able to use the original command (Ctrl+Alt+Z) on ArcgisPRO and it worked right off the bat.